# Sending email with Ruby through mutt

Tags: ruby, linux, mutt

I'm trying to send an email in this way:

```
 path_to_file="/home/username/tmp/filename.html" 

 subject="My Subject"
   to.each do |address|
    cmd = "`echo \"#{body}\" | mutt -s \"#{subject}\" #{address} -a #{path_to_file}`"
    system(cmd)
   end
 end
```

This is running on a unix machine, the file has an html extenxion and contains html code.
I receive the file correctly, with the same filename and extension, the problem is that is completely empty, this is strange because when i run the same command (mutt) from the terminal, applying the same path to file:

```
echo "body here" | mutt -s "some subject" mamail@mail.com -a ${path_to_file}
```

Then it works just fine.
Any idea?

Comment: `path_to_file` is not defined anywhere in this question

Comment: add `set content_type=text/html`